# Default implementation of splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

Hi, the default implementation of splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation: method in the UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol is as given below. -

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);
```

How to locate this implementation in Xcode? I can go over to the declaration of this method in UISplitViewController.h file in Xcode, but not the implementation. So how does one know the default implementation of any built-in method?

Answer (score 2):

The method `shouldHideViewController` was only introduced in `iOS 5`.

If your target build settings 'deployment target' are set to anything before `iOS 5`, the `Xcode` editor won't offer you this method through autocompletion (or any other that aren't available to your target `iOS` version).

To check the `iOS Deployment Target` in `Xcode`, select your target, and look under the `Summary` tab. Make sure this is at least `iOS 5`.

For some methods only introduced in `iOS`, such as `setTintColor` methods, you can dynamically check the version in your code, but in this example (`shouldHideViewController`), I think you're going to want to choose to use it, and go with `iOS 5` only, or choose to not use it and use popovers.

Comment: Thanks. The deployment target in Summary is specified as '5.0' and the Base SDK in Build Settings is specified as 'Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)'. However, the question is that 'is it possible to check the default implementation of any method in a built-in protocol' or for that metter, do they even have any default implementations?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  Xcode generates templates for new files of the major class types.  I sometimes create new files so I can cut & paste the latest template code, but I don't know of a way to insert that within an existing file - autocompletion isn't _that_ complete ;-)